# Picturebox transparency

Tags: winforms, picturebox

can anyone help me how to apply transparency on picturebox on Winforms? I have a panel as a main container having a background picture, and I have a picturebox which overlapped on it. So all I need is to have a transparency on picturebox.

Comment: would it be safe to assume you're using winforms?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Backcolor` property of the PictureBox to `Transparent`.

Ofcourse, make sure that the image you're using is transparent as well (i.e. no background color).

Comment: I think what he actually meant was "How to make the whole picturebox semi-transparent", so you could see 'through' the picturebox.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of the PictureBox and set the Back Color to "Transparent".

With code you can do it like:

```
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```